# ImageMagick: How to resize proportionally with mogrify without a background

Tags: imagemagick, mogrify

I was following this example http://cubiq.org/create-fixed-size-thumbnails-with-imagemagick, and it's exactly what I want to do with the image, with the exception of having the background leftovers (i.e. the white borders). Is there a way to do this, and possibly crop the white background out? Is there another way to do this? The re-size needs to be proportional, so I don't just want to set a width re-size limit or height limit, but proportionally re-size the image.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The example you link to uses this command:

```
mogrify             \
  -resize 80x80     \
  -background white \
  -gravity center   \
  -extent 80x80     \
  -format jpg       \
  -quality 75       \
  -path thumbs      \
   *.jpg
```

First, `mogrify` is a bit dangerous. It manipulates your originals inline, and it overwrites the originals. If something goes wrong you have lost your originals, and are stuck with the wrong-gone results. In your case the `-path thumbs` however alleviates this danger, because makes sure the results will be written to sub directory *thumbs*

Another ImageMagick command, `convert`, can keep your originals and do the same manipulation as `mogrify`:

```
convert             \
   input.jpg        \
  -resize 80x80     \
  -background white \
  -gravity center   \
  -extent 80x80     \
  -quality 75       \
   thumbs/output.jpg
```

If want the **same result, but just not the white canvas extensions** (originally added to make the result a square 80x80 image), just leave away the `-extent 80x80` parameter (the `-background white` and `gravity center` are superfluous too):

```
convert             \
   input.jpg        \
  -resize 80x80     \
  -quality 75       \
   thumbs/output.jpg
```

or

```
mogrify             \
  -resize 80x80     \
  -format jpg       \
  -quality 75       \
  -path thumbs      \
   *.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks, Kurt, I will address the mogrify issue. I wasn't very sure what the difference was between it and convert, but I did actually set the -path just in case. I certainly didn't want to overwrite master image files.

Comment: `-resize 80x-1` will calculate height proportionally automatically.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old thread, but by using the -write flag with the -set flag, one can write to files in the same directory without overwriting the original files:

```
mogrify -resize 80x80 \
-set filename:name "%t_small.%e" \
-write "%[filename:name]" \
*.jpg
```

As noted at http://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php, %t is the filename without extension and %e is the extension. So the output of image.jpg would be a thumbnail image_small.jpg.

Answer (score 7):

This is the command I use each time I want to batch resized everything to 1920x and keep aspect ratio.

> mogrify -path . -resize 1920x1920 -format "_resized.jpg" -quality 70 *.jpg

Comment: Actually `-resize 1920x1920` keeps aspect ratio, resulting in `max(width,height)` equal to 1920.